# layout preview in android studio while working with mipmap

Tags: android

I have read this article on [mipmap](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html) before going through `mipmap` practically to understand its concept over `drawable`.

What i've faced is,

1. While working with `mipmap` `layout-preview` is not correct, while using image from `mipmap` folder.
2. Is mipmap only for `launcher icon` ? do i need to manually create all `drawable` folders(`drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi` etc.) for all other `View`'s (`Button`, `ImageView`, etc.) image? If so then why don't android studio is not creating all `drawable` folder after creating new project?

I've also searched this issue but failed to get any useful or relevant link. I don't know what's wrong with `mipmap` because it seems fine while run code only layout preview is not correct.

**Update :**

Currently for workaround i've used `mipmap` folder only for `launcher-icon` and for all other `Views` i've manually created `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi` etc.
to make `layout-preview` fine.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

> According to [this Google Post](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)

The mipmap folders are only for placing your app icons.
Any other drawable resources(images and drawable .xml) you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as before Android 4.3.

This is the best practice to place your app icons in mipmap - folders (not the drawable - folders) because they are used at resolutions different from the device’s current density.

> For referencing the mipmap - folders ensure you are using the
>   following reference: android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

You can also check [the more about the Mipmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap)

Answer (score -1):

Yes they are talking about the Launcher icon for the Nexus family. So this would be good practice if you do so. And for other resources you have to keep going in the same way As you always do.